# Haproxy backend servers on different interfaces

Tags: port, haproxy, connection, eth0

I have a haproxy server which gets limited to some 60k connections. I think it is because of ephemeral port limit as I have 1:1 connection mapping, so all my outgoing connections go to the same server.

Here is what I think could help me: I can add a new network interface (eth1) with a new IP. I would then add a duplicate backend server definition and I believe the new destination will get a new ephemeral port limit as long as it uses a different interface. This should let my connection counts grow.

However, I can't seem to find a way to force haproxy to use eth0 for one backend server definition and eth1 for another. Is it possible to do that, or are there other ways of achieving what I need?

The system in question is running Debian and haproxy 1.4.8 (default on Debian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From HAProxy manual, section 5:

> The "source" parameter sets the source address which will be used
>   when   connecting to the server. It follows the exact same parameters
>   and principle   as the backend "source" keyword, except that it only
>   applies to the server   referencing it. Please consult the "source"
>   keyword for details.

Answer (score 0):

Florin's answer is great.

Failing that (say, if this wasn't HAproxy), a workaround would have been to configure an address in a separate subnet on the secondary device.

The backend server would need to be reachable in that subnet as well, of course - the new `server` declaration would not be a duplicate, but rather an independent entry that would incidentally end up at the same machine.